# How to change author of the commit on gitHub?

Tags: github, author

I have configured user.name (Justyna) in git through VSC terminal. When I commit changes in local environment, terminal shows "Justyna" as an author of commits. But when I push changes on github, in my github repository I can see my "github nickname" as an author of the commit and not my real name (they're different). Is it possible to change settings so that github shows the same name as my terminal?

I used those commands:
git config --global user.name "My Name"
git config --global user.email me@example.com

I looked through settings available on github, but found nothing.